# changing two elements while hovering one div

Tags: html, css, hover

I'd like to ask a question which I can't find an answer for anywhere. I'm sure it's pretty simple, but how do I put these two css sentences (or functions, I don't know?) together in one?

```
.key:hover p{
    color:red;
}

.key:hover {
    background-color: #999999;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe they are called "rules." Could you explain why you want to put these together exactly? Or another example of where you might want this kind of thing? It seems like this is a fine way to accomplish this. There are all sorts of reasons to combine things, but I don't see the urgency to do it here.

Comment: @Xander's answer takes care of business assuming that there isn't any other text, h2 for example, that you don't want red.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is likely what you're after. This solution, like any other, is affected by other applicable CSS definitions that may already exist.

```
.key:hover {
    color:red;
    background-color: #999999;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want hover function to be triggered only when the mouse is hovered on exactly `<p>` however this is not possible as you can see in [**live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RPLCK/)

```
.key
{
    background-color: green;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}

.key:hover {
    background-color: red;


}
.key:hover p{
    background-color: blue;
}
```